# Cross platform data synchronization

Tags: android, sql, synchronization

Im going to develop a android application, the data which i want to be viewed/edited on a Pc/Browser. I've not touched on synchronization before, so if anybody knows any good sources about the complexity and problems with data syncronization would be great.

I will have a central mySql database, how will I control the data synchronization from the sqlite to mysql and also when data is changed from PC side. Another problem that could occur data being written at the same time and dealing with duplicates.

I realise this isn't really a programming question and is a bit vague, if anyone experienced in this area could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use timestamps. Database engines provide them automatically. When you connect to your DB and see, that the timestamp you stored from the previous operation is different, then proceed with syncing
2. If you are afraid that the data may be overwritten because of two synchronisations done in the same time, use locking bit (a column in database with boolean value or a file). At the beginning of every sync check if it is not "locked", and if it's not - lock the remaining part of your database. If it is locked - check again soon and try to synchronise the data again.

Comment: Re: #2, for automatic conflict resolution, Conflict-free Replicated Data Type (CRDT) is a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of synchronizing data, why not access the data real time? For this to work from a mobile device you would need a web service fronting the database. You can either develop that specifically for your purposes or use a generic solution developed specifically for this purpose. Check out [this blog post](http://www.slashdb.com/2013/03/14/database-gateway-for-mobile-and-web-apps/) (disclaimer: I work there)