# Cross Platform, Open Source, Data Synchronization Strategy

Tags: mobile, synchronization, cross-platform, desktop-application

The goal is to have occasionally connected clients belonging to **one user** running on an array of different platforms be able to share a common dataset. Server will be GNU/Linux. Platforms and devices initially targeted include: GNU/Linux, Android and Windows on x86_64, i686, ARMv7, ARMv8. Possible consideration given to OSX and iOS devices. The UI toolkit will likely be Qt5. The non-interface logic will be in c++. My code will be licensed under the GPL or AGPL.

Many applications like Google's Maps, for instance, require a reliable connection to work effectively. My design decision is that each client should be fully functional without a network connection, assuming that the user has not used a different device/platform to change the data. In such cases, only a synchronization with network access should be necessary.

Some applications are written with hand-rolled data persistence and synchronization layers customized for each platform or subset of platforms. While this is quite effective, it is beyond the available skill and manpower available (just me :) ).

Also, though I'm somewhat conditioned by past experience to think of things from a relational database perspective, the data I'm expecting is probably better suited to a JSON/NoSQL database. Though there is UNQLite, it has no more synchronization capabilities than SQLite. And things like MongoDB, CouchDB, etc. are, as far as I have found, solely targeting the data center or cloud at the moment. Really, the same seems to be true of SQL solutions. Are there truly cross platform databases that have native synchronization/replication capabilities?

I've spent the past weeks looking at a variety of options, but have found little truly useful. The closest I've seen to something useful is CouchBase; however, it seems to be rather unstable (from an API standpoint, not relating to crashes), has a huge set of dependencies, seems to be nothing but a SQLite wrapper on mobile platforms and has limited developer docs at the moment.

If there is an applicable library or toolkit, please point it out. If not, or **if this is excessively "discussion oriented", please kindly point me to an appropriate resource to find help before closing this question.**

Notes:

- [How would you design & implement a Cross Platform synchronization mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397274/how-would-you-design-implement-a-cross-platform-synchronization-mechanism?rq=1) Talks about hand rolling solutions. If this is the only way to go, I would appreciate references specifically applicable to SQLite3 since I know that it is stable and available on just about everything but the kitchen sink.
- [Cross platform data synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801248/cross-platform-data-synchronization?rq=1) Does not really address anything significant. One of the main concerns I have is effectively synchronizing data while minimizing network bandwidth requirements. Even in the US, there are vast areas where high speed data is simply not available. To me, usability in the widest range of circumstances is important.
- [How to Synchronize Android Database with an online SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299208/how-to-synchronize-android-database-with-an-online-sql-server?rq=1) This post is somewhat helpful but I am a total, absolute novice at developing for anything but *NIX on servers and workstations. Again, if it is necessary to do SQL based persistence for this set of requirements, more pointers to guidance would be helpful.